Django UpdateView doesn't save a new value
I have a forum app, its structure is "forum-subforum-topic-comment". Topics are exclusive for their subforum, comments are exclusive for their topic and displayed only inside the topic. Views are implemented mostly via class-based-views.
While creating a new Topic, you have to define not only the field subject, but also the initial comment, first_comment. It is pretty similar to objects of the Comment model, but is effectively a part of the Topic model.
So, the problem is that while my UpdateView for comments (UpdateComment) works well, and comments are edited without any issues, the UpdateView for a first_comment of Topic objects, though returning no error, doesn't edit the field (the page is rendered, it works, the terminal even shows some amount of data near the code 200 - but the content of the field stays the same).
models.py (Topic and Comment models only):
class Topic(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(verbose_name='Заголовок', max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_comment = models.TextField(verbose_name='Сообщение', max_length=2000, default='')
    slug = models.SlugField(default='', unique=True, max_length=25, editable=False)
    subforum = models.ForeignKey('Subforum', verbose_name='Раздел',
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='subforum')
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='Создатель темы',
                                on_delete=models.SET('deleted'), related_name='creator')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    closed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    objects = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['id']
        verbose_name = 'Обсуждения'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Обсуждения'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = f'topic-{slugify(self.subject)}'
        return super(Topic, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('forum:topic', kwargs={'topic_slug': self.slug, 'subforum_slug': self.subforum.slug})


class Comment(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey('Topic', verbose_name='Тема', on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                              related_name='comments')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='Комментатор',
                               on_delete=models.SET('deleted'), related_name='author')
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name='Текст', max_length=2000)
    created = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Дата публикации', auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Дата изменения', auto_now=True)
    objects = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created']
        verbose_name = 'Комментарии'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Комментарии'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Post of {self.topic.subject} is posted by {self.author.username}.'

views.py (ShowTopic, AddTopic, UpdateFirstComment and UpdateComment for comparison):
class ShowTopic(DetailView):
    model = Topic
    template_name = "forum/topic.html"
    slug_url_kwarg = 'topic_slug'
    context_object_name = 'topic'
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        topic = self.get_object()

        comments_list = Comment.objects.filter(topic=topic).order_by('created')
        paginator = Paginator(comments_list, self.paginate_by)
        page_number = self.request.GET.get('page', 1)
        page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)

        context.update({
            'menu': menu,
            'comments': page_obj,
            'page_obj': page_obj,
            'is_paginated': page_obj.has_other_pages(),
            'paginator': paginator,
            'comm_num': comments_list.count(),
        })

        return context


class AddTopic(LoginRequiredMixin, DataMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = AddTopicForm
    template_name = 'forum/addtopic.html'
    page_title = 'Create a new topic'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('forum:topic', kwargs={
            'subforum_slug': self.kwargs['subforum_slug'], 'topic_slug': self.object.slug})

    def form_valid(self, form):
        subforum = Subforum.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['subforum_slug'])
        form.instance.creator = self.request.user
        form.instance.subforum = subforum
        return super(AddTopic, self).form_valid(form)


class AddComment(LoginRequiredMixin, DataMixin, CreateView):
    model = Comment
    form_class = AddCommentForm
    template_name = 'forum/addcomment.html'
    page_title = 'Leave a comment'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('forum:topic', kwargs={
            'subforum_slug': self.kwargs['subforum_slug'],
            'topic_slug': self.kwargs['topic_slug']})

    def form_valid(self, form):
        topic = Topic.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['topic_slug'])
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.instance.topic = topic
        return super(AddComment, self).form_valid(form)


class UpdateFirstComment(LoginRequiredMixin, DataMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Topic
    form_class = AddTopicForm
    template_name = 'forum/editcomment.html'
    page_title = 'Edit comment'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('forum:topic', kwargs={
            'subforum_slug': self.kwargs['subforum_slug'],
            'topic_slug': self.kwargs['topic_slug']
        })

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return Topic.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['topic_slug'], subforum__slug=self.kwargs['subforum_slug'])

    def form_valid(self, form):
        topic = self.get_object()
        first_comment = topic.first_comment
        form.instance.creator = self.request.user
        form.instance.topic = topic
        form.instance.first_comment = first_comment
        return super(UpdateFirstComment, self).form_valid(form)


class UpdateComment(LoginRequiredMixin, DataMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Comment
    form_class = AddCommentForm
    context_object_name = 'comment'
    template_name = 'forum/editcomment.html'
    page_title = 'Edit comment'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('forum:topic', kwargs={
            'subforum_slug': self.kwargs['subforum_slug'],
            'topic_slug': self.kwargs['topic_slug']
        })

urls.py
app_name = 'forum'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', SubForumListView.as_view(), name='forum'),
    path('<slug:subforum_slug>/', TopicListView.as_view(), name='subforum'),
    path('<slug:subforum_slug>/add_topic/', AddTopic.as_view(), name="add_topic"),
    path('<slug:subforum_slug>/topics/<slug:topic_slug>/', ShowTopic.as_view(), name='topic'),
    path('<slug:subforum_slug>/topics/<slug:topic_slug>/edit_topic/', UpdateFirstComment.as_view(), name='edit_topic'),
    path('<slug:subforum_slug>/topics/<slug:topic_slug>/add_comment/', AddComment.as_view(), name="add_comment"),
    path('<slug:subforum_slug>/topics/<slug:topic_slug>/<int:pk>/edit_comment/', UpdateComment.as_view(), name="edit_comment"),
    path('<slug:subforum_slug>/topics/<slug:topic_slug>/<int:pk>/delete_comment/', DeleteComment.as_view(), name="delete_comment"),
]

If something else is necessary to understand the context better, please inform me.

aren't you supposed to form.save()?

in form_valid method of your UpdateFirstComment class, the first line with self.get_object().. try replacing that with  self.object = form.save(commit=False) and reference self.object vs topic. this is typically done to populate the form.object and allows you to add more fields that may be required. I don't know if this will solve it or not, but it is how i typically start my form_valid() methods. Not sure this will fix it, but worth a try!

@folengateis, Eric, it works, gentlemen! I offer you to write a proper answer, I'll accept it as a solution.

@folengateis, I haven't actually found the place in the tutorial where it says that form has to be saved. Either to blame it on my eyes, either it's hidden somewhere in an unobvious place.
